# Multi select no adminLte Laravel 5.8

Tags: adminlte, laravel-5.8

Preciso criar um multi select na página e estou usando o `AdminLte`, a situação é a seguinte: Um curso pode ter várias disciplinas (*o banco esta pronto com os relacionamentos certos*)

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="disciplinas[]" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach($disciplinas as $disciplina)
        <option value="{{ $disciplina->id_disciplina }}">{{ $disciplina->nome }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Logo abaixo coloco o Js

```
<script>
$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    placeholder: 'Selecione as disciplinas',
    allowClear: true
});
</script>
```

Ele carrega como um textarea e não monta o select. Chega a listar as disciplinas no Loop, mas não deixa selecionar mais de uma opção.

A olhei e está carregando os CDNS:

```
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css
```

Minha necessidade é a seguinte: Como montar corretamente esse multi select e como enviar para o Controller para salvar as opções escolhidas.

Comment: Pra onde eu devo mover essa pergunta?